# Why there are no full lenght independent cartoon animated movies created in Blender?

Tags: animation, 3d, blender

I have been searching for an indie movie that is completely done in Blender, but the longest animation I have found was about 15 minutes long.

Are there any full length animated cartoons/movies (~90 minutes)?

I have found only this:
http://www.blender.org/features-gallery/movies/

You can tell me also commercial titles if there are any, but I haven't found any so I am interested if they are any or not?

Most of the movies from big studios are using Maya, so I am curious if any indie companies are using Blender or not, because I think that if a group of enthusiasts invest 2 or 3 years in something like Big Buck Bunny (it's only 10 minutes long, but created in Blender and I think it is really nice ely done, especially if you consider it was done about 5 years ago):

Comment: This question is running very close to the "no actual problem to be solved" variety discouraged in the [types of questions to avoid asking](http://avp.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on the help page.  Also, it's a bit unclear what you're asking, apart from the title.

Comment: @JoshP Why there are no full lenght independent cartoon animated movies created in Blender? Could you explain it somehow?

Comment: I cannot... not my area of expertise.  I had mentioned the "unclear" bit, as that is another of the criteria to watch out for, for off-topic questions.

Comment: Isn't there a Blender exchange for questions like these?

Comment: I am one who is not ignorant the great capabilities of blender and the power of other underrated to some open-source software available today. Teams of good scriptwriters, sound experts, modellers, animators need to get together and make a good movie or tv anime. and prove the commercial tool fans wrong. I would freely join that group. And yes, I am convinced Blender has overtook the Maya software over the past few years.

Comment: @JohnRygielski, http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoshP wow, finally an exchange for Blender. Can you please move it there, if you are a moderator? Thanks.

Comment: @Derfder, I asked... the blender mods didn't want the question.  I'm not sure they have video embedding either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, to make a full length movie requires a lot of man hours and generally a decent budget.  It becomes more cost effective to get real animation software when dealing with a full length film than trying to struggle through with something like Blender.

Don't get me wrong, Blender is great for what it is as a free product, but, at least as of the last time I was able to seriously work with it a few years back, it was nothing at all compared to the capabilities of one of the high end systems like Maya or SoftImage.

Both the ease of working with the tools and the improved collaboration workflows make it so that using a commercial system may likely be cheaper in the long run due to time saved for a long project like a full length movie.  It's certainly easier, even if costs are just close to comparable.

It's also worth noting that Maya isn't the only platform used by the big studios.  Several use their own in-house systems, Maya, SoftImage and Cinema4D are also all used pretty extensively.  3D Studio Max is also sometimes used, though it has found more of a niche in the video game market.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Blender can be e.g. altered if something is missing because it's opensource. So the indie comapny can create a specific tool. e.g. to generate same things programatically etc. so that can speed things up. You cannot do that with Maya, Max or others, because they are proprietary software. Btw. Blender is more intuitive and easier to work with than Maya.

Comment: @Derfder - not without considerable development effort and time.  You are talking feature sets that took man decades, if not man centuries, to build and polish and get working well.  It's both cheaper to buy the software and cheaper to do it the hard way than it is to implement the software features that would be needed.  Blender is a great project for people to play around with writing code for a 3d engine and modeling tool, but it is done for reasons of curiosity and interest in the software for the software's sake, not for reasons of trying to make an actual film.

Comment: @Derfder - also, you can extend any of the major software packages and every house out there does.  Custom generation utilities are produced, special effects packs are made, even entire custom workflows and menu systems are built.  Maya and SoftImage at least both give great ability for dev staff to easily leverage existing functionality in to new custom features.  The ease with which they can be extended actually is simpler than extending Blender in many ways since there is more existing functionality exposed to be able to work with.

Comment: @Derfder and Blender may be easier for a beginner to work with than Maya, but that's like saying Paint is easier to work with than Photoshop.  There is a lot of complexity to Maya and even more complexity to SoftImage, but to a trained artist, those features that are missing from Blender that make it "easier" actually make life substantially more difficult due to missing options and functionality that are needed to do the job well.

Answer (score 2):

There actually are two films that I am aware of. One is 'Naught 5' and Plumiferos. You can easily Google to see the production websites.

Comment: Welcome to Video Production on Stack Exchange.  It is never too late to post an answer.  You can also use embedded links if you want in the titles to link to the websites for the projects you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Blender is now in the actual version of 2.73 a huge competitor to all the big proprietary animation programs.

The problem is not even the software, but the budget for employing scriptwriters (most important, because the story is number one of the list for a successful movie), voice actors, designers, matte painters, rigging specialists, animators, musicians, compositors ... you would need a budget of several millions.

I have seen a movie done entirely in 3DS Max Studio. The "uberector" (that is the name for a person who makes a movie entirely alone), has switched now to Blender 3D because it's becoming better and better and reaching a point where you don't even think about to use Maya or Lightwave or whatever is on the market.

But the main problem remains always the same: Do you have a story for a full featured movie? Yes? Ok, then have you draw a storyboard for the 80 minutes of movie? Have you already the music? And have you asked you're friends and neighbors if they are willed to play a role as voice actors? If yes I guess you have spend the last 3 years only on this part of the movie making process. ... Only now comes the part of 3D animation, compositing, modelling, rigging, ... it's hard work indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently finished and released my third animated feature that I created entirely by myself, aside from the talent of my voice actors,  Cold Dark Mirror, which I created using Blender.  http://originalsineproductions.com/ColdDarkMirror.html

Other Uberectors working in blender:

Spooktergeist, who is working on his film "River of Dried Blood"

Klaus TehKurious, with "City of Dying Head"